# Como uso payara Server netbeans y MySql

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, netbeans

Título: Error 404 Not Found en Payara Server

Cuerpo:

Estoy recibiendo un error 404 Not Found cuando intento acceder a la ruta /NuevoUsuario en mi aplicación Java EE desplegada en Payara Server.

El código de mi aplicación es el siguiente:

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

 @POST
 @Path("NuevoUsuario")
 public Response ping1(){

 Usuario user = new Usuario();
 user.setNombre("Asdrubal");

 em.persist(user);                   

 return Response
        .ok("Hola desde Payara Server/Netbeans/NuevoUsuario")
        .build();
 }
```

He verificado el archivo web.xml de mi aplicación y la ruta /NuevoUsuario está asociada al método ping1(). También he verificado el código de mi aplicación y no hay errores.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a solucionar este error?

El ping de payara esta bien, los JDBC estan bien, ya hice el mapeo por medio del JDBC.

Cuando ejecuto una peticion  @POST en el metodo "ping1", sin incluir el @PersistenceContext, sin la entidad Usuario el se ejecuta bien, pero cuando agrego el @PersistenceContext, la entidad Usuario y hago el em.persist(user); me devuelve el error.

---

@RubioRic
Esta es la traza de mi servidor:

Respuesta del servidor: Payara Server 6.2023.10 #badassfish - Error report

## HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

---

**type** Status report

**message**Not Found

**description**The requested resource is not available.

---

#### Payara Server 6.2023.10 #badassfish

Comment: Buenas, Asdrubal, parece claro que el error se produce al persistir. ¿Qué te aparece en las trazas del servidor? Da la sensación de que ese error 404 está enmascarando otro problema distinto a que el recurso no se encuentra